# pandas selection from list

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I am looking for a way to select pandas rows where either:

all items in a list is present in either one of the columns in that row,

or where a minimum number of list items is present in that row

If I have something simple as this:

```
test_df=pd.DataFrame([['test1', 'test2', 'test3'], 
['test4', 'test5', 'test6'], ['test2', 'test3', 'test2'], ['`test1', 'test2', 'test5']], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

col1    col2    col3
0   test1   test2   test3
1   test4   test5   test6
2   test2   test3   test1
3   test1   test2   test5

test_list=['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

First query: all items in the list is present in either columns like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   test1   test2   test3
2   test2   test3   test1
```

And a query where minimum two items from the list is present in either column like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   test1   test2   test3
2   test2   test3   test1
3   test1   test2   test5
```

Is there a way to do this?

I can select rows where minimum one is present by this (ugly i know, but works) but can't figure out how to expand this to min. two

```
test_df[(test_df['col1'].isin(test_list) |(test_df['col2'].isin(test_list)|(test_df['col3'].isin(test_list))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for test membership with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test match all values per rows in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = test_df[test_df.isin(test_list).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
    col1   col2   col3
0  test1  test2  test3
2  test2  test3  test2
```

Or you can count matched values with `sum` and test if greater or equal by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html):

```
N = 2
df = test_df[test_df.isin(test_list).sum(axis=1).ge(N)]
print (df)
    col1   col2   col3
0  test1  test2  test3
2  test2  test3  test2
3  test1  test2  test5
```

If need test columns by list:

```
cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
df = test_df[test_df[cols].isin(test_list).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
    col1   col2   col3
0  test1  test2  test3
2  test2  test3  test2
```

---

```
N = 2
cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
df = test_df[test_df[cols].isin(test_list).sum(axis=1).ge(N)]
print (df)
    col1   col2   col3
0  test1  test2  test3
2  test2  test3  test2
3  test1  test2  test5
```